# Php function strstr does not convert first char when with diacritics

Tags: php, file-upload, utf-8, character-encoding, diacritics

I have HTML in UTF-8 with upload form. After upload I convert given filename in PHP using

`$filename = strtr ($filename, $conversion_chart);`

When using Safari or Chrome on Mac it looks like it is working, but when the first character in the name of file has diacritics (like á, Š, Ž...), this char is not converted and is missing in output. All other chars are converted correctly. It works like this:

"Ušiak.doc" -> "usiak.doc" - correct conversion

"Šiak.doc" -> "iak.doc" - bad conversion

Update: Recently I found that from Firefox it is always bad conversion. Like:
"uŠiak.doc" -> "uSÌiak.doc"

Here is actual php code: 
http://test.awaldorf.cz/inc/prihlaska.php.noparse

and HTML: http://test.awaldorf.cz/prihlasky.php

Comment: Please post a concrete code sample that we can run ourselves. What does `$filename` and `$conversion_chart` contain exactly?

Comment: @deceze i added source files

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP source must be properly UTF8 encoded. As it is not (it does not matter it looks fine in your editor, it's not UTF8) your `$conversion_chart` is broken. You should either use UTF8 for source file correctly, or replace `Š` with numeric codes to avoid encoding problems

Comment: I think it is correct utf8. When i change encoding in editors or viewers (Textwrangler, Safari, Chrome, Dreamviewer)  to anything other than utf8, it looks wrong. But in UTF8 the chars looks correct. So this is IMHO not the reason of problem.